# (Java) How to define what letters/numbers/signs are allowed to be input by user?

Tags: java, exception, java.util.scanner

I am creating program in Java, which adds, deduct and multiply hexadecimal numbers (without converting them into decimals), set this aside.

I am using scanner.nextLine() to catch hex numbers. My question is how can I limit what can be input by user. I want to throw exception if anything else than 0-9 && a-f was input.

Thanks for advice.

Answer (score 1):

Computers perform math with binary (not decimal and not hex). Call `Integer.parseInt(str, 16)` in a `try-catch` if you get a [`NumberFormatException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NumberFormatException.html) it wasn't a valid hex encoded `int`.

Answer (score 0):

There is a `nextInt` method on the `Scanner` class that accepts a radix as a parameter.  For example:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
int val = sc.nextInt(16);
```

After this code executes, val should be an integer assuming a valid hexadecimal input.  An `InputMismatchException` will be thrown if the input is not a valid base 16 int.